# Facing a issue in contact us page looks like JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i’m facing a issue in contact us page of my website. It’s showing some java script code under email image. I don’t now why it’s showing i tried to solve but can’t. Please help me out why this is showing. Here is screenshot [Screenshoot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Aijm.png). Please help me out how to fix it? I'm not a developer but can solve if anyone give me the solution. Here's affected url: https://www.hrdbearing.com/contact-us.

I want to know the solution of this problem.

Comment: Could you add some of your code and what you have tried to fix this issue?

Comment: It's not javascript; it looks like some kind of markup. Maybe a tag didn't get closed. From the html, it's just extra text hanging around, but could easily be something from the backend. What's "woodmart"? Seems to be related to that.

Comment: If this is being generated from backend then surely someone forgot to close a tag.

Comment: Can you checked the screenshot?

Comment: then how to close this tag please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the plugin you use to build your pages is not working since it is showing the markup text instead of the page content.

Check if it is installed and try to update.